# Unable to get MIME version of a Message using $value

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am unable to get MIME for a message using `$value` like specified in the documentation. How to get MIME?

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
  .url("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/k4ZDQ5LTgzMTYtNGZhYS04ZTU3LWZhMjFmZmUzNmE1YwBGAAAAAABzUENX1K4kR6h6KAAA7ENoUb5BySZFX6KemUxNwAAAv_a5nAAA=/?value")
  .build();
Response response = null;
String body;
try {
  response = client.newCall(request).execute();
  body = response.body().string();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URLs are incorrect, they're using `/?value` but should be using `/$value` (`$` not `?`). The `$value` is part of the path, not a query param:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/4aade2547798441eab5188a7a2436bc1/$value
```

Comment: Yes, that worked but in case using graphClient custom url it gives exception java.io.BufferedInputStream cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonObject

Comment: JsonObject obj = graphClient.customRequest(
    "/me/messages/ m-ID /$value")
    .buildRequest()
.get();
This request returns bufferedInputStream but it can't be stored in BufferedInputStream it gives compile time error if we do so. It can only be stored in a JsonObject. What should we do?

Comment: Try encoding it as `%24value`

Comment: I get the value to Object class and then type casted it to BufferedInputStream. IT worked.

Comment: I get the value to Object class and then type casted it to BufferedInputStream. IT worked. But my graphClient worked for 60 minutes only. I guess the access token expired. How to get refresh token in java SDK

Comment: Token lifetime is typically an hour. There is documentation on how to obtain and refresh tokens at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/

Comment: Java IAuthenticationResult doesn't provide the method to get refresh token. While debugging i found out that refresh token is there in result but there isn't any method to get it. Also If we get the refresh token how to use it in java SDK to re-initialize the GraphClient.

Comment: The SDK itself doesn't really handle authentication. The default mechanism (`ImplicitMSALAuthenticationProvider) leverages MSAL. Since the Implicit grant doesn't support Refresh, you will likely need to implement a custom auth provider. This is documented at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/blob/dev/docs/CustomAuthenticationProvider.md

Comment: Let's say I have an IGraphServiceClient object. Now, the token used in it expires. I want to provide a new token to IGRaphServiceClient. How should we do it? Is there any approach other than re-initializing the object. We are application permissions here