# How do I fetch nested attachments to an Email Attachment using Graph API?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I have a use case where while reading a user emails,  I need access to the attachments that are part of the attachment which is of Email Type(ItemAttachment/message), nested attachments, using MS Graph API.

I have browsed through multiple links in the MS graph doc but couldn't fine any solution to this.

Does Graph API provides a way to fetch the nested attachments from an Email kind of attachment ?

Comment: Please go through this [link](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/34632904-graph-api-retrieving-nested-mail-attachments-not-a).

Comment: For converting it to MIME use this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-mime-message). Please remember that this is still in beta.

Comment: Thanks Shiva, I went through this , but was wondering how is it possible to create this request (with "$value") through Graph API Java sdk. Couldn't find any method that can help me create request with "$value" like the one mentioned in the doc. `(GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages/AAMkAGUzY5QKiAAA=/attachments/AAMkAGUzY5QKiAAABEgAQAK8ktgiIO19OqkvUZAqLmyQ=/$value)`.

Comment: Try this java code snippet `InputStream stream = graphClient.me().messages("{messageid}").attachments("{attachmentid}").content()
 .buildRequest()
 .get();`

Comment: If this doesn't work, use httpclient for this as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59562518/unable-to-get-mime-version-of-a-message-using-value) as there is already a feature request in [JAVA SDK](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/39322333-please-add-get-mime-content-of-a-message-in-java-s).

Comment: Go ahead, upvote the above uservoice incase if you want Graph team to consider implementing it.

Comment: This query `JsonObject jsonObject = graphClient.customRequest("/users/userID/messages/messageID/$value").buildRequest().get()` return null object for me. But if I remove the `$value` from the request I get the message but not the MIME .

Comment: The MIME content will always have Content-Type as text/plain. So as I suggested above  use the code in the above SO Thread link and see how it goes.

Comment: I am trying using the customRequest() which returns JsonObject specified in the comment section In the Thread [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59562518/unable-to-get-mime-version-of-a-message-using-value]. .

Comment: Moving this to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this [link](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/34632904-graph-api-retrieving-nested-mail-attachments-not-a). For converting it to MIME use this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-mime-message). Please remember that this is still in beta.

Use httpclient for this as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59562518/unable-to-get-mime-version-of-a-message-using-value) as there is already a feature request in [JAVA SDK](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/39322333-please-add-get-mime-content-of-a-message-in-java-s). Please upvote it so that it may be implemented in the future.

I have tested it in many ways and I was able to get only text/plain format. And [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-mime-message#example) is how it looks.

Answer (score 0):

Considering below email hierarchy

```
MainEmail
    -- Nested Email 1
            -- Nested Email 2
                    -- File Attachment
            -- File Attachment
    -- File Attachment
```

================================================================

```
int MAX_NESTED_LEVEL = 10;
List<Attachment> nestedAttachedFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Get all the attachment of the Main Email and iterate it)
{
    if (attachment instanceof ItemAttachment  && "message/rfc822".equalsIgnoreCase(attachment.contentType)) {
        /* By calling getNestedEmailAttachments method graph api is loading all the nested attachments
           for the primary attachment of the main email in one go only (maximum level upt 30). see
           documentation for ItemAttachment Resource. */
        List<Attachment> nestedEmailAttachments = getNestedEmailAttachments(emailMessage.id, attachment.id);
        nestedAttachedFiles.addAll(processNestedEmailMessage(nestedEmailAttachments));
    }
}


//Below are the methods which are used for pulling the nested emails

// Here parentMessageId is Main email ID and attachedMessageId will be Nested Email 1
// This will load all the hierarchy of Nested Email 1
public List<Attachment> getNestedEmailAttachments(String parentMessageID, String attachedMessageID) 
{
    List<Attachment> attachments = new ArrayList<>();
    LinkedList<Option> requestOptions = new LinkedList<>();
    Option queryOption = new QueryOption("expand", "microsoft.graph.itemattachment/item");
    requestOptions.add(queryOption);
    URL requestURL = graphServiceClient.me()
            .messages(parentMessageID)
            .attachments(attachedMessageID)
            .buildRequest(requestOptions).getRequestUrl();
    ItemAttachment itemAttachment = new ItemAttachmentRequestBuilder(requestURL.toString(),
            graphServiceClient, null).buildRequest().get();
    OutlookItem outlookItem = itemAttachment.item;
    if (outlookItem instanceof Message) {
        AttachmentCollectionPage embeddedAttachments = ((Message) outlookItem).attachments;
        if (embeddedAttachments != null) {
            attachments.addAll(embeddedAttachments.getCurrentPage());
        }
    }
    return attachments;
}

// Here will iterator over all the attachments and nested email of Nested Email 1
private static List<Attachment> processNestedEmailMessage(List<Attachment> emailAttachments) throws Exception 
{
    List<Attachment> nestedAttachment = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        for (Attachment attachment1 : emailAttachments) {
            if (attachment1 instanceof ItemAttachment && "message/rfc822".equalsIgnoreCase(attachment1.contentType)) {
                nestedAttachment.addAll(getNestedEmailFileAttachments((ItemAttachment) attachment1, 1));
            } else {
                nestedAttachment.add(attachment1);
            }
        }
    } catch (GraphServiceException exe) {
        throw new Exception("Failed to process nested email's ", exe);
    }
    return nestedAttachment;
}


private static List<Attachment> getNestedEmailFileAttachments(ItemAttachment nestedItem, int nestedLevel) 
{
    List<Attachment> fileAttachments = new ArrayList<>();

    OutlookItem oItem = nestedItem.item;
    if (oItem instanceof Message) {
        if (nestedLevel == MAX_NESTED_LEVEL || ((Message) oItem).attachments == null) {
            return fileAttachments;
        }
        AttachmentCollectionPage emailAttachments = ((Message) oItem).attachments;
        for (Attachment emailAttachment : emailAttachments.getCurrentPage()) {
            if (emailAttachment instanceof ItemAttachment && "message/rfc822".equalsIgnoreCase(emailAttachment.contentType)) {
                ++nestedLevel;
                List<Attachment> attachments = getNestedEmailFileAttachments((ItemAttachment) emailAttachment, nestedLevel);
                fileAttachments.addAll(attachments);
            } else {
                fileAttachments.add(emailAttachment);
            }
        }
    }
  return fileAttachments;
}
```

This is the complete working code.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?  I can't seem to get the OutlookItem converted to a Message object.